# outputting from indesign using xml

Tags: xml, adobe-indesign

We have an indesign file with xml coding. When the elements are output to a PDF some of the xml elements do not display correctly. Is it typical that you need to edit those in the PDF file, or do we have incorrect xml/indesign settings?

Is it appropriate for me to ask this forum if we can hire someone to help us fix the issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is not a hiring website. You might try Adobe Indesign forums or freelancers hiring websites